# Parameters not passing through AJAX post using tinyMCE- Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm using rails and tinyMCE and I'm having troubles getting the params to pass through to the controller. I believe it's something to do with the actual ajax call because I cannot get a value in my params.

I created test data because I thought something was wrong with var serialized but this is all i got when i called 'params' in my terminal ( im using binding.pry in my controller).

terminal output :

```
   => <ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"forms", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
enter code here
```

this is my ajax call:

```
$("#tinymceForm").on('submit',"click", function (e) {
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
    var serialized = tinyMCE.activeEditor.serialize();
    var f = "test";
    $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: action,
         data: f,
         async: false,
         success: function (data, textStatus, request) {
            alert('Succes occurred');
         },
         error: function (req, status, error) {
            alert(status);
            alert(error);
                alert("Error occurred!");
             }
        });
return false;
});
```

Comment: what is url: action, I don't see action variable.

Comment: The var action which is the path that other vars will be posted to, is not defined ..